# customize creates custom-set-faces unintentionally

Tags: org-mode, faces, customize, variables

I just edited the variable `org-M-RET-may-split-line` with easy costumize, saved and applied. I checked my dotfile right afterwards and noticed that

`(custom-set-faces
'(default ((t (:foreground "#DCDCCC" :background "#3F3F3F")))))`

was added to my dotfile. This already happened a few times to me when using easy customize. Any idea how to prevent this?

EDIT: I'm able to reproduce the issue:

- start spacemacs with `emacs`
- open dotfile with `SPC f e d`
- `SPC f1 python-shell-interpreter`
- change value to `python3`
- apply and save
- bottom of dotfile, this is what was added:

> ```
> ;; Do not write anything past this comment. This is where Emacs will
> ;; auto-generate custom variable definitions.
> (custom-set-variables
>  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
>  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
>  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
>  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
>  '(fci-rule-color "#383838" t)
>  '(nrepl-message-colors
>    (quote
>     ("#CC9393" "#DFAF8F" "#F0DFAF" "#7F9F7F" "#BFEBBF" "#93E0E3" "#94BFF3" "#DC8CC3")))
>  '(org-M-RET-may-split-line (quote ((default))))
>  '(pdf-view-midnight-colors (quote ("#DCDCCC" . "#383838")))
>  '(python-shell-interpreter "python3")
>  '(vc-annotate-background "#2B2B2B")
>  '(vc-annotate-color-map
>    (quote
>     ((20 . "#BC8383")
>      (40 . "#CC9393")
>      (60 . "#DFAF8F")
>      (80 . "#D0BF8F")
>      (100 . "#E0CF9F")
>      (120 . "#F0DFAF")
>      (140 . "#5F7F5F")
>      (160 . "#7F9F7F")
>      (180 . "#8FB28F")
>      (200 . "#9FC59F")
>      (220 . "#AFD8AF")
>      (240 . "#BFEBBF")
>      (260 . "#93E0E3")
>      (280 . "#6CA0A3")
>      (300 . "#7CB8BB")
>      (320 . "#8CD0D3")
>      (340 . "#94BFF3")
>      (360 . "#DC8CC3"))))
>  '(vc-annotate-very-old-color "#DC8CC3"))
> (custom-set-faces
>  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
>  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
>  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
>  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
>  '(default ((t (:family "Office Code Pro" :foundry "NATH" :slant normal :weight normal :height 120 :width normal)))))
> ```

Comment: Can you provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce what you reported, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? That will likely help you get an answer. If you cannot, then try to bisect your init file to find out what seems to cause the behavior.

Comment: @Drew added and example

Comment: Thx. Can you simplify the recipe - is all of it necessary? For example, is using Spacemacs necessary to get the behavior? Please try to provide a minimal example - just what is needed.

Comment: @user430 I tried using spacemacs and was not able to replicate your problem. If you do not want this customized value for the default face, then I suggest that you use `M-x customize-face RET default RET` and select the "Revert..." button and choose the "Erase Customizations" option (to both remove it from the init file and -- importantly -- ensure that the current Emacs session will not add it back).

Comment: If it comes back after that, then something elsewhere in your config is customizing that face.

Answer (score 1):

Do not touch the entries which customize inserts, thats all.

But you can also split the stuff which customize writes into another file with:

```
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/custom.el")
(load custom-file)
```

in your init.el. Then customize will write only to that file.

Comment: Two pieces of good advice. But this does not answer the question, I think. The question seems to be how does it happen that customizing a variable ends up (also?) customizing a face.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Spacemacs, but I looked for the function that saves customize buffers and found `custom-save-all`.  It calls both `custom-save-variables` and `custom-save-faces`.  So any time you save all customizations, both get called.

Looking at `custom-save-faces`, it doesn't check to see if you've changed any faces before it inserts `custom-set-faces` into your init or custom file - it only deletes the one that's there and replaces it with a newly constructed sexp.  What seems strange to me is that you have a default face set there, while I do not; I don't know if that's a difference in Emacs (I'm on 24.5.1) or if it's something added by Spacemacs.

In any event, the hacky solution would be to redefine `custom-save-faces` to just return nil.  That should work, but you'd lose the ability to customize faces.  I haven't tested this, though.  A proper solution would be much more involved.